# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with initializing react state value with an ES6 new Map() object

Tags: reactjs, sockets

I have a top-level React component that is initialized like the following using craco:

```
class Map extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // socket: openSocket('http://localhost:5000/test'),
      junction_pos_data: [],
      xpndr_data: [],
      pods_complete_data: new Map(),
    };
```

For some reason, craco does not like me using the new Map as a React stateful value, even though I use it in children states just fine.  The socket connection is commented out, and when I use any other type here, I'm not getting the Range Error either.  This is what the console is throwing at me:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new Map (Map.js:77)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
    at new Map (Map.js:82)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow` Javascript version ! (lol)

Comment: thats what i get for coding after 10pm ‍♂️  thanks @chris b!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you named your react component `Map`, the component is recursively initializing itself and it's causing an infinite loop.  Renaming your class component should fix it, and it's generally a good idea to avoid naming classes or variables after reserved words or primitive data/object types (Array, Object, etc.) to prevent unexpected behaviors.